# tabu and extra vertical space for tall equation

Tags: tables, equations, tabu, vertical-spacing, parbox

### Q:

Why [`tabu`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) adds extra vertical space before first line of cell contents if the second line of a paragraph is too tall?

MWE below contains three use cases:

1. `tabular` (from [`array`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array)) approach with `p{}` columns;
2. [`tabu`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) approach with `X[]` columns and very tall equation in the second line (see first row in table 2);
3. number 2 variant with not so tall equation in the second line (see second row in table 2).

### Output:

[image]

### Comments

Each paragraph in each cell should be top aligned, i.e. the first line of text and the fist line of equation should be typeset on the same baseline. The first variant (uses `tabular`) looks just fine. The third variant (uses [`tabu`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) and empty square brackets) looks fine too. But the second one is typeset with extra vertical space before first line.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}


\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{\texttt{tabular} approach}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth} p{0.3\linewidth} p{0.3\linewidth}}
 \hline
 \raggedright\arraybackslash
 Left column. A few lines of text
   & \raggedright\arraybackslash
     $ a = b \times$
     \newline
     $ \times
       \max
       \left\lbrace
        \begin{array}{c}
         \\[-2ex]
         \left[
          \cfrac{c^{-1}_\text{D} - e}{\tilde{f}^{2}_{0}}
         \right]
         \\\\[-2ex]
         \left[
          \cfrac{\hat{g}^{3}_\text{H} + 2}{k^{}_\text{L}}
         \right]
         \\\\[-2ex]
        \end{array}
       \right\rbrace$
   & \raggedright\arraybackslash
     Right column. A few lines of text
 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{\texttt{tabu} approach}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[1,l] X[1,l] X[1,l]}
 \hline
 Left column. A few lines of text
   & $ a = b \times$
     \newline
     $ \times
       \max
       \left\lbrace
        \begin{array}{c}
         \\[-2ex]
         \left[
          \cfrac{c^{-1}_\text{D} - e}{\tilde{f}^{2}_{0}}
         \right]
         \\\\[-2ex]
         \left[
          \cfrac{\hat{g}^{3}_\text{H} + 2}{k^{}_\text{L}}
         \right]
         \\\\[-2ex]
        \end{array}
       \right\rbrace$
   & Right column. A few lines of text
 \\
 \hline
 One more line
   & $ a = b \times$
     \newline
     $ \times
       \max
       \left\lbrace
        \begin{array}{c}
         \\[-2ex]
         \left[
          \,
         \right]
         \\\\[-2ex]
         \left[
          \,
         \right]
         \\\\[-2ex]
        \end{array}
       \right\rbrace$
   & This is correct
 \\
 \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's right, and typographically, it looks better. Usually, the vertical spacing w.r.t. horizontal lines in latex is much too tight. That's why the `cellspace` package was designed.

Comment: tabu is broken and unmaintained. It is not recommended to use it. See the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu